# how to open a txt file?

Tags: c

I am working on a C project. In this project I need to open a txt file and read from this file. This is what i did :

```
FILE* our_file=fopen ("init_file","r" );
fscanf(our_file,"%s\n",(*sys)->system_name);
```

I believe that the first line will open the file and the second one will read the first line in the file and put it in `(*sys)->system_name`.
My problem is that the file doeasn't open, even though I put it in the workspace where I saved my project.

Comment: Reading a text file line-by-line is the standard lesson in every beginner's C book! What is your specific problem you don't find answered? Read [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: i saied that my problem is how to open the file !! the file doeasn't open i don't why

Comment: Try to fscanf into a string with enough allocated memory. If it works, you'll know your problem comes from `(*sys)->system_name`

Comment: i did that the project stops to work .. and the debbug stops in the first line : fopen..

Comment: does init_file have a file extension?

Answer (score -1):

Reading and opening are two different things. For opening, one should always check if opening has succeeded before trying to do something. Something like that would be safe :

```
FILE* file = NULL;
file = fopen(path, mode);
if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file");
else {
     // read, write or do what you want to do
}
```

As for reading, you'll find billion of answer on Stack Overflow which may help you. Ask again if nothing seems to work for you.

Also, you should check the success of closing your file, since failing to close it might cause opening problems later.

Comment: yes but i didn't add the if  condtion because i dont know what to put instead of stderr

Comment: Put stdout if you prefer. stderr should work anyway. Are you 100% sure your path is correct ?

Comment: where should i put the txt file?

Comment: Wherever you want, you just need to have the right to access to it (some places on your computer are protected so don't put it there obviously) and the correct path. You can use relative or absolute path, relative may be better if your file is within your project, absolute if it is not.

Comment: so i did what yo told me and i got the message : "Could not open file" which means the file didn't open although i have put it in the work space of the project i am working on..

Comment: @lauren: We are not a tutoring/remote debugging site! The problems you have in this and your other questions are answered by any good C book. Please get one and work through the chapters! C is not a language to be learned by trial&error.

Comment: well i didn't ask ypu to debbug my code ! i didn't even put my code lol i just asked you how can i read my file and thats it

Comment: It iss likely to be one of the three following things : your file is already open, your path is wrong or the mode of opening does not exist. I can't really do much more for you since you gave almost zero details about your code and how your project is builded. If you decide to, edit your question and tell me.

Comment: i am still stuck on this ! i want to update my question

Comment: Well you can. Just edit it. Consider posting  the full code and may be a screen shot of your project directory.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use an absolute path, not relative. 
To achive this, get working directory, and concatenate with your filename.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * fp;
   char cwd[1024];
   if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
   strcat(cwd, "\\init_file.txt");

   fp = fopen (cwd, "r");

   if (fp == NULL)
       return(0);

   return(0);
}
```

Also, don't forget to place your file into the working directory.

Comment: It is nonsense to get the CWD and concatenate it with the filename, because that's what's done with a relative path. And directory seperator is `/`, not `\`. It is not on your system? See the problem?!